# how to set background as black when jquery popup opens

Tags: jquery

I have the jquery popup.I need to set background color when popup opens.

How to set background when popup opens.

jquery code :

```
function load_forgot() {         
        $('.pop_forgot').fadeIn('fast'); 
        document.body.style.backgroundColor='#000';     
        $('#wrapper').css({'opacity': '0.3'});    
    }
    function unload_forgot() {
        $('.pop_forgot').fadeOut('fast');    
    }
    jQuery(document).on('click', 'selecter_to_which_triggering_the_popup', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            url: some_url_which_gives_dynamic_data_as_html,
            beforeSend: function(data){ },
            success: function(data){
                load_forgot(data);           
            }
            });
            $('.pop_forgot_close').click(function() {
                unload_forgot();
            });
        }
    );
```

Comment: are you trying to set the background of the body as black or the whole parent must become black?

Comment: Isn't this more of a CSS question?

Comment: he will need javascript/jquery to change it once the modal opens anyway

Comment: @G.Mendes : Yes background of the parent window become black.

Comment: generally its put an overlay `div` over the parent which looks like to be your `#wrapper` div since its being used transparency, would be helpful if you post your relevant html or set up a http://jsfiddle.net